# Generate Guid upon field creation in caml field definition

Tags: column, caml

I'm trying to figure out a way to generate a new Guid upon field creation without using event handling.

I.e something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{a35657bf-c5af-4e86-a0a9-4c378e26ec2b}" Group="Membership" Name="UserId" DisplayName="Användarid" Type="Guid" ReadOnly="TRUE">
    <DefaultValue>=[System.Guid]::NewGuid()</DefaultValue>
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

There is of course already the GUID column that I could copy the Guid from but I'm not sure if that is possible or how that would be done without using event handling.

Any advices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to declaratively set anything like this (as technically it would no longer be declarative).

Doing this in a feature receiver is a trivial task, however.